# Python function unable to return result

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Below is a function which is supposed to return longest palindromic substring of a string. Though the function itself looks alright but for some strange reason It is not returning the string. Any Idea what I am missing here?

```
def largest(string, repeat=None):
    if len(string) <= 1 and repeat:
        return repeat[max(repeat.keys())]
    elif len(string) <= 1:
        return string
    list_str = list(string)
    repeat = repeat or {}
    end_index = -1
    while len(list_str)+end_index:
        construct = list_str[0:len(list_str)+end_index+1]
        reversed_construct = construct.copy()
        reversed_construct.reverse()
        if construct == reversed_construct:
            repeat[len(construct)] = ''.join(construct)
        end_index -= 1
    string = string[1:]
    largest(string, repeat=repeat)
```

Comment: `largest(string, repeat=repeat)` -> `return largest(string, repeat=repeat)`

Comment: @DennisSlimmers That would still be recursive..

Comment: @Rawing Got it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In a order to return a value from a recursive function, one must put `return recursive_function(x)` so that  when a value is returned it is placed in a position where the data can be accessed by the function 'above' it, so to speak.

```
 def Factorial(total,counter):
    if counter == 0:    #tests whether the counter is at 0
        return(total)   #if it is at 0 return the product of the consectutive numbers between 0 and starting counter
    total *= counter    #set the total to itself times the current pass counter
    return Recursion(total,(counter-1)) #return the value of this function passing the total and the counter -1
```

You see that in this example for me to hold the value that was passed previously I have to return it so that after all the recursions are completed they will all pass the data back up the chain of function.